# Automatically use saved proxy authentication on Windows

Tags: proxy, authentication

Is there some method to prevent Windows (or the browser) from popping up the proxy authentication dialog every time I open a browser? Surely there should be some setting to use my user name and password automatically?

The saved information does appear in the pop-up authentication window, I want to avoid the pop-up entirely (since it serves no purpose, and gets annoying as I have to click it hundreds of times)

Note that I have no access to the proxy server itself, or know what type it is.

In case this information is necessary - Wireshark shows the following

```
CONNECT www.google.com:443 HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Connection: keep-alive
Host: www.google.com

HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required
Proxy-Authenticate: BASIC realm="InetPass"
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Proxy-Connection: close
Set-Cookie: BCSI-CS-e9e87a9198535326=2; Path=/
Connection: close
Content-Length: 1785
```

(HTML page follows, displayed if authentication fails)

Thanks in advance

---

### Update

Found a solution for Firefox (version 23) from [here](http://nasarabna.wordpress.com/2010/03/03/firefox-keeps-prompting-for-proxy-authentication/) (comment by Sherwin).
In *about:config*, set `signon.autologin.proxy` to **true**. 
The other settings given in the blog entry had no effect.

Now I wonder whether there is a generic solution for all browsers, or at least for IE.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is NTLM authentication. (I might be wrong)

If you are using Firefox, try using the plugin called "Integrated Authentication for Firefox". You can search it in Firefox Add-on Manager.

The website is here: https://code.google.com/p/firefox-ntlmauth/

Comment: Thanks but that didn't work. Installed the add-on but the same prompt appears (I may be doing it wrong)
The website is blocked at work, I'll check it out at home later today.

Comment: Apparently it is basic authentication. Found details here: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2617.txt